How to reverse all cards in bulk in Anki
I accidentally created hundreds of cards "upside down" in Anki. (I was confusing Front and Back.) How do I flip all of them at once?
All the cards I want to flip are in the same deck, if that can help.
I'm running Anki 23.12.1 on GNU/Linux Debian Bookworm (12).
